# SwiftUI Drag Gesture inside of the UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uipageviewcontroller

I have a SwfitUI project and start to build `UIPageViewController`. Inside the pages I have `VStack` like this:

```swift
VStack {
  // some code hare
}.gesture(
  DragGesture()
    .onChanged({ self.onDragChanged($0) })
    .onEnded({
       self.onDragEnded($0)
     })
)
```

This fragment of code (I only need to drag up and down) works as expected. But there is one problem after I add this DragGesture my `UIPageViewController` subview, native `UIPageViewController` swipe (left and right) stop working.

Any Solution hare?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use instead `.simultaneousGesture` modifier?

Comment: @Asperi Hello, you mean like this: ```.simultaneousGesture(DragGesture().etc```? Yes, I did, but same result. drag gesture inside the subpage block native swipe.

Comment: Try the `gestureRecognizers` property of the PageViewController to check if they are being overridden (ie being failed) by the SwiftUI views gesture, or (more likely) not recognized at all.